# I want the ViewPager to be in full screen - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have some issues with the `ViewPager` I am using. I want it to be in full screen, but for some reason there are some edges that won't disappear. How can I solve this?

Code from the `XML`-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Main.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: ok so remove padding from parent relative layout and make view pager as match parent

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: instead of write thanks you can upvote or accept the answer which help to resolve issue.

Comment: remove padding and margin attributes

Comment: How can I accept a comment?

Comment: @thehulk: You can't accept comments, you can only accept answers (however it is possible to upvote a comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove paddings from all four sides. By default when you create the activity using AS, AS will add padding to your main view. Below is the layout without external padding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Main.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as like following way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Main.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all of android:padding from RelativeLayout
and remove android:layout_centerVertical and android:layout_centerHorizontal
from ViewPager